# Emacs (spacemacs) not keeping extensions

Tags: package, spacemacs

I installed emacs 25.1.1 on fedora and cloned the spacemacs environment. Then, I launch emacs and install some packages (e.g. magit). When I close and reopen emacs all my extensions must be reinstalled to use them. I can see the files I need exist under .emacs.d/.cache.

Any idea why it is not installing them permanently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected, from the FAQ:

**Why are packages installed with package-install automatically deleted by Spacemacs when it boots?**

By default Spacemacs will keep only the packages that you use (i.e. the packages belonging to a layer explicitly listed in the variable `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`).

To install packages that don't not belong to any Spacemacs layers, you can:

- use the variable `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`.
- or create a configuration layer configuring the package and add this layer to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`
- or set the variable `dotspacemacs-install-packages` to `used-but-keep-unused` which will prevent Spacemacs from removing the packages you installed manually.

---

To check if Spacemacs supports the package you want to install press `SPC h SPC` and then look for the package you are interested in, for instance `magit`, you will see that `magit` is part of the `git` layer. Add `git` to the variable `dotspacemacs-configutation-layers` and press `SPC f e R` to reload the configuration in place. You should end with `magit` installed, it will remain installed as long as you use the `git` layer or you list `magit` in `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`.

Be sure to read the docstrings of all the dotspacemacs variables in your dotfile, especially the variables in `dotspacemacs/layers` function.